# SQL Server : how to write a CASE query for a different INSERT INTO statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, insert-into

The question is referring to a T-SQL query.

There are two tables:

**Table_A:**

```
 A_ID | Category | SomeValue .
 -----+----------+-----------.
   0  |    1     |   ...     .
   1  |    1     |   ...     .
   2  |    2     |   ...     .
   2  |    2     |   ...     .
```

and **Table_B** that should get filled by the Category condition of Table_A. Depending on the categories of Table_A I would like to write some data into **column 1 OR column 2** of a second table. The other column shall remain null:

```
 B_ID | cat_x    | cat_y     .
 -----+----------+-----------.
   0  | someval  |   null    . //Category was 1
   1  |  null    |  someval  . //Category was 2
   2  |  null    |  someval  . //Category was 2
   2  | someval  |   null    . //Category was 1
```

My input is a whole table. For every row it has to look up the goal column to write in.

I tried to work with CASE, but I didn't got it. Here is some pseudo code that might help you to understand:

```
CASE
   WHEN Category=1
      THEN 
         INSERT INTO (B_ID,cat_x)
             SELECT (someval) //ID could get filled automatically
             FROM sometable
   WHEN Category = 2
      THEN 
         INSERT INTO (B_ID,cat_y)
             SELECT (someval) //ID could get filled automatically
             FROM sometable
END
```

My biggest problem I guess is how to write the syntax for the condition/when-clause.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) which returns a single, atomic result (from various options) - it is **NOT** (like in other languages) a construct to control the flow of execution and execute one piece of code - or another, depending on conditions. This needs to be handled with classic `IF .... ELSE ...` blocks

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.  The `case` expression should be part of the `select query:

```
INSERT INTO (B_ID, cat_x, cat_y)
        SELECT (case when a.category = 1 then someval end),
               (case when a.category = 2 then someval end)
        FROM A
        WHERE category IN (1, 2);
```

Comment: Oh this way! I was thinking in the wrong direction. I will try it when I have the next possibility. I will give you a feedback very soon. Thanks!